# Comparing Three Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I’m wanting to be able to automatically highlight cells That are blank in the intersection of 2 other cells if their value is 0

Like say B10 = 1
and i8 =1

the intersection of those would be cell I10 and if that is 0 I’m wanting the box to be highlighted

however say B10 = 1  and J8 equals 0
j10 would be left alone.

comparing the Values From I8-P8 to check if they are >0 and if B10-B309 >0 Then check if the intersection from B’s Row against whichever columns row 8. is 0 and if so highlights. Hopefully that made sense.

I did get it to work with conditional formatting, however. I'd have to adjust the formula for each and every cell in 8 Columns times 300 rows... It gets tedious, especially as I’m looking into expanding the document past 300.

The current formula I used is

```
=and($B10>0, I$8>0, I10=0)
```

I'm not sure if I should use VBA to do this instead of conditional formatting.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image: Pic 3]

Comment: Your formula seems to work for me, but I may misunderstand the description you gave of the spreadsheet. Can you maybe post a screen capture of the spreadsheet with the expected result? You can upload on on http://imgur.com and someone with enough reputation will likely embed it for you

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aFZFCkd

Comment: It works, However having to adjust the formula for 2400+ Cells.. Is excessive. and i was wanting to see if there was a better way. Those Three cells i programmed it for but show kinda what I am talking about as-well as my other conditional formatting formulas in work

Comment: When you use a custom formula for conditional formatting, you can apply the same formula to a larger range, and it will automatically adjust the formula to apply to each cell, the same as when you do autofill. Write the conditional formatting formula as it would be written in the Top Left Cell of the range, it will do the rest.